# Wordpress Theme Overriding Plugin

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I installed a plugin for a dropdown menu (Max Mega Menus) but my wordpress theme (Spacing) is overriding it. I followed the instructions on the MMM website on removing residual styling so that the plugin would work but when I deleted the codes as instructed (I think I picked the right one) then the menu disappeared altogether. Here are the instructions I was following: https://www.maxmegamenu.com/documentation/faqs/removing-residual-styling/
Here is the current coding. I tried deleting every combination of things besides the wp_nav_menu part, as instructed.

```
<div id="header">

<div id="wrapper">  

<div class="container clearfix">

<div id="navigation">
<?php wp_nav_menu(array('menu' => 'custom_menu')); ?> 

            <?php if($of_option['st_responsive']) responsive_select_nav() ?>

        </div>        

    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please go to Mega Menu > General Settings > Menu Locations. You'll see a list of menu locations that your theme has registered. Expand the one for the top menu and copy the PHP include code. Then replace the call to wp_nav_menu in your header.php file with it.

In short, your wp_nav_menu call is missing the required 'theme_location' argument.